# php always trying to load extensions from relative path

Tags: php, path, extension

PHP is always trying to load extensions from a relative path. For example:

php.ini

```
extension=/vld.so
```

> Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library './/vld.so' - .//vld.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place your extension in the correct directory.

PHP looks for extensions in the directory specified in the [`extension_dir` directive in php.ini](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.extension-dir). The `extension` directive simply specifies one or more extensions that PHP will attempt to load, relative to the `extension_dir` path.

Comment: One thing i want to add: The default of extension_dir is /path/to/your/php/. If you now use extension=/vld.so it will actually look for /path/to/your/php/vld.so. To use absolute paths you need to use extension_dir=/